# Modeling the creation of transverse waves

Tags: classical-mechanics, waves, non-equilibrium

Suppose I hang one end of a jump rope against a wall and start waving the other end. 
I'm interested in knowing the behavior of the jump rope as it starts generating waves.
In other words, how can I model the dynamics of this system before it reaches steady-state equilibrium?

You can make whatever assumptions you want. For example, you can make it a frictionless rope without the influence gravity. You can make my waving of the rope whatever function you want, like you can make my swinging a sine wave centered around the height the rope is hanging at.

Additionally I'm familiar with tools used in Lagrangian mechanics, variational calculus, PDEs and greens functions (if that makes things easier).

I'm particularly interested in seeing how exactly modes develop in wavelike systems, and am thinking that the solution to this question will illuminate things for me.

Comment: If you know all of these things, what's wrong with using a wave equation as an approximation of a real rope? Having said that, the frictionless ideal rope, just like an ideal wave equation, will never "forget" about its transient solution. For that we need a system with some form of loss (even if it's only in one point).

Comment: @CuriousOne OP says "before it reaches steady state equilibrium."

Comment: @soumyadeep: OP said he wants to see how "modes develop". There won't be much to see, if the transient solution sticks around and if the system is being driven with one of its Eigenfrequencies, its total energy will keep growing indefinitely without damping. I am getting the feeling that the OP may have the wrong idea about the difference between the Eigenmodes and the driven solutions of conservative linear systems? The implicit expectation seems to be much more in tune with a lossy system, which, eventually, will decay to its longest "ringing" mode, irrespective of excitation spectrum.

Comment: @CuriousOne I didn't mean to force you to use a system without any friction - I was just using that as an example trying to explain that I don't care about the particular parameters. You can have gravity on or off. You can turn whatever forms of friction you want on or off. You can choose whatever driving frequencies you want. Whatever you think illustrates the generation the dynamics of the system the best. 
I'm interested in understanding what you're saying: that the rope "will decay to its longest 'ringing mode', irrespective of excitation spectrum."
Care to explain this in detail?

Comment: @StevenSagona: That was my point: systems with friction will behave VERY differently from those without. If you know Green's functions, you already have the tool you need to understand the transient solutions of wave equations: it's basically introducing a delay of the original signal, and now you can add different kinds of reflection (open or closed end) to it, if you like. The problem with these is, that whatever you put in will "circulate" in the medium forever. The only way to "take it out" is by adding the exact same waveform with opposite sign.

Comment: @CuriousOne I see your point. Can we go in detail over the case where there is friction? What would the greens function solution look like? 
Am I finding the solution to an inhomogeneous wave equation?
I'm familiar with finding the wave equation without friction (as seen [here](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~feldman/m256/wave.pdf)), but I don't know how you would include friction. 
So if it _is_ just solving the inhomogeous pde using greens functions, then how do I incorporate the boundary conditions into the greens function solution?

Comment: @StevenSagona: hmm... I am inclined to make a comment about insufficient effort... can you google "green's function damped wave equation" and read trough the plethora of papers on how to solve this problem with different methods?

Comment: You may be interested in [this Computational Science post](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/7049) on solving the wave equation numerically (specifically using Matlab, but the method is applicable in all languages).